# Asynchronous wait for database-value in Playframework (2.4-M3) and Slick (3.0.0-RC3)

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, slick

I'd like to keep my application as asynchronously as possible. Now I have this repository:

```
object LanguageRepository extends LanguageRepositoryTrait
{
    private val languages = TableQuery[Languages]
    private def db:Database = Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource())

    private def filterQuery(id: Long): Query[Languages, Language, Seq] = languages.filter(_.id === id)
    private def filterCode(code: String): Query[Languages, Language, Seq] = languages.filter(_.code === code)
    private def all() : Query[Languages, Language, Seq] = languages

    override def find(id: Long): Future[Language]  =
    {
        try db.run(filterQuery(id).result.head)
        finally db.close()
    }

    override def find(code: String): Future[Language] =
    {
        try db.run(filterCode(code).result.head)
        finally db.close()
    }

    override def get(): Future[Seq[Language]] =
    {
        try db.run(all().result)
        finally db.close()
    }
}
```

When I call a url like "domain.tld/{language}" I want to check whether the given language(code) actually exists. Like, if the site isn't available in french (fr) I want to throw an exception or a 404.

Now, my problem is that this whole asynchronously thing is pretty cool and while I do think to understand the theory behind it, I'm rather baffled right now. I mean, I want this to be non-blocking (and asynchronously, which is the reason for me using Future and async ;))

In my controller I want to do something like:

```
def checkLanguage(language:String) = Action
{
  val lang:Future[Language] = languageRepository.find(language)

 lang.onComplete
 {
   case Success(s) = Ok("Yay")
   case Failure(f) = 404("Oh no!")
 }
}
```

Of course this can't work, but that's a schema of how I want to have things working. I want to wait or postpone the rendering of the site, until it's confirmed that the given language-code is valid or invalid.

I had a look at the Playframeworks async-documentation for 2.3.6 (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.6/ScalaAsync) but I couldn't really get this to work as intended.

Any input appreciated!

Comment: First of all, Asynchronous != non blocking.  Why do you say "this can't work", your `find` returns a `Future[Language]` so it is async (but not non-blocking) and you have an `onComplete` handler to render the result. What is not working exactly?

Comment: @vptheron well the method must return an Action, so this can't compile because the return values are in the "onComplete{}"-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your db query don't use .head instead  use .headOption. that way ur return type will be a Future [Option [x]]

In ur controller u can do something  like this

```
Lang.map { case Some (x) => Ok (x)
  case None =>  404 ( "not found ")
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Action.async {
    val lang:Future[Option[Language]] = languageRepository.find(language)
    lang.map {l => l.map{_ => Ok("Yay") }.getOrElse(NotFound("Oh no!"))
}
```

First of all, I am assuming that if there is a possibility that a language will not exist then `languageRepository.find(language)` should return an `Option` of `Language`. Change `Future[Language]` to `Future[Result]` and use `Action.async` instead of `Action`

Now for some explanation, `Action` takes a block whose result should be `Result`. However, what you get is `Future[Option[Language]]`. Play provides `async` method for `Action` which needs `Future[Result]` and it takes cares of completing the request.

So, you need to convert `Future[Option[Language]]` to `Future[Result]`.

```
 lang.map {l => l.map{_ => Ok("Yay") }.getOrElse(NotFound("Oh no!"))
```

We map over the lang, if the `Option[Language]` is not `None` then we convert it to `Ok("yay")` else we convert it to `NotFound`

Even, If you don't get `Option[Language]`, the idea remains the same. Convert `Future[Language]` to `Future[Result]` and use `Action.async` instead of `Action`

Comment: Sorre (non-native speaker) I don't really get what you do. Where do I change "Future[Language]" to "Future[Result]"? In my Repository, I assume? In the Controller I leave it at Future[Option[Language]]? Because Result has no map function?! But that way it won't compile, so I am missing something here, I guess. Could you please explain what I need to change in the controller and what in the repository? Thanks!

Comment: Try this, val lang:Future[Option[Language]] = languageRepository.find(language); lang.map(l => Ok("Yay")) and use Action.async instead of Action

Comment: thanks, but this can't compile obviously. the "find"-method returns a Future[Language] not a "Future[Option[Language]]"

Comment: Oops .. I meant val lang:Future[Language] = languageRepository.find(language); lang.map(l => Ok("Yay")) and use Action.async instead of Action .. map is defined on a Future also.

Comment: Works, but now there is no "else"-part of course. can I incorporate that somehow? If the controller doesn't find a language (like domain.tld/test/) it throws an NoSuchElementException and I'd like to handle that directly in the controller.

Comment: I tried it like this:  lang.map
  {
      case(l:Language) => Ok("Yay")
      case(_) => NotFound("Booo")
  } which works great for the positive case, but the other one never gets matched :/ I could try with try{} and catch but this looks awful, don't you think? There must be a more eloquent way.

Comment: lang.map{l => Ok("Yay"))}.recover {case NoSuchElementException => NotFound("Booo") }. Using recover is the standard way of handling failures in Futures. Read more at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html